# Vim, colourschemes and setting ctermbg doesn't work properly

Tags: vim, highlight, color-scheme

I want to highlight the cursorline in Vim, depending on if I'm in insert mode or in command mode (using it in Gnome Terminal/Gnu Screen on Ubuntu) and some people suggested I should use these commands in .vimrc

```
au InsertEnter * set nocursorline
au InsertLeave * set cursorline
hi cursorline cterm=underline ctermbg=243
```

All of the above commands work fine if I use them in Vim directly (use the settings temporarily until the next restart).

I also load a colourscheme named "wombat" in .vimrc, but there are several problems occurring when using the same commands in .vimrc:

- If I put the ctermbg-command after loading the scheme (as I should), the scheme is somehow ignored/not loaded/not used or whatever. Meaning, that vim comes up with some standard colours.
- If I put the ctermbg-command before loading the scheme, the highlighting doesn't work but the scheme is loaded.
- If I only try to set cterm, then the scheme is loaded, but the underlining doesn't happen. No matter which command comes last.

Any thoughts?

Comment: after scheme case: I guess there was a typo/ or  other error before your colorscheme loading. it has nothing to do with your cursorline settings. because if you typed the 3 commands in vim, and it worked.  there is no difference from putting the 3 lines in the very end of your vimrc.

Comment: Like I told you on #vim, color settings should be in your colorscheme: find the line with "CursorLine" and customize it to your liking. Doing anything else will get you nowhere. Also make sure your `$TERM` in screen is set to `screen-256color`.

Comment: Another thing, there's lots and lots of spaces after your lines, if these spaces are in your `~/.vimrc` and are not an artifact of copy/pasting I strongly suggest you to clean it up.

Comment: I'm not sure about "Doing anything else will get you nowhere".  Modifying highlights in `.vimrc` after loading a colorscheme works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because your colorscheme overwrite your custom settings. I'll suggest the following:

1. Leave the two lines in vimrc

   ```
   au InsertEnter * set nocursorline
   au InsertLeave * set cursorline
   ```
2. Fork your colour scheme, give it a new name, then refer it in vimrc

   ```
   colorscheme wombat-custom
   ```
3. Hack the scheme.

   - Find the code about `cursorline`, revise its `ctermbg` to whatever you want
   - Also pay attention to `Normal` `ctermbg`. It's the normal background, better to be similar but different from cursorline, so that you'll know whether you are in insert mode.

Side note: If you want you can version control whole colorscheme folder so that you know how to get back if necessary. My practice is to version control whole .vim folder, though with a bit more complex settings.

Comment: I tried to change the wombat scheme itself and to fork it, but the results are still the same. As soon as I add the definition for ctermbg the scheme isn't loaded anymore.

Comment: It's impossible the scheme is not loaded. Just type `:colorscheme` you'll found what scheme you are using.

Comment: It seems the colourscheme is loaded, but the colours are all wrong as soon as I change the line:
`hi CursorLine guibg=#2d2d2d`
to
`hi CursorLine guibg=#2d2d2d cterm=underline ctermbg=243`

Comment: Hard to figure out without knowing the details. But Wrong is better than no change. Just check what's changed then play it around you'll find solution quickly.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried it, Wombat behaved differently than any of the other colorschemes I was using, so it might just be broken outside of the GUI, since it doesn't directly define any cterm highlights.

You shouldn't need to hack the colorscheme file, though. The ColorScheme autocommand runs commands after a colorscheme is loaded, so if you want this behavior for every colorscheme you use (as this will override all of them), then you can add another line to force it:

```
hi cursorline cterm=underline ctermbg=243
au ColorScheme * hi cursorline cterm=underline ctermbg=243
```

Additionally, I noticed that the InsertEnter/InsertLeave autocommands did not immediately draw the line properly when I switched into and out of insert mode, so I changed your autocommands to be:

```
au InsertEnter * set nocursorline | redraw!
au InsertLeave * set cursorline | redraw!
```

And that made everything look like it was working for me.